# C++ Vector memory management in Game of Life

Tags: c++, memory-management, game-of-life

I'm writing a simulator for Conway's Game of Life ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)) in C++ and I'm trying to make the code as idiomatic as possible.

The central object is a double array to represent the board:

```
typedef vector<vector<bool> > Board;
```

My `main` method has a `Board b` as a local variable, and I'm passing the board to several methods that update the board, draw the board, and so on.  Is it better (that is, more efficient and/or idiomatic) to use methods like

```
void update(Board *board);

int main() {
   Board b;
   //...
   update(&b);
   //...
}
```

or in this way:

```
void update(Board & board);

int main() {
   Board b;
   //...
   update(b);
   //...
}
```

Which is the proper choice for idiomatic C++?

Comment: I don't know C++ but I think its the game of life thing is pretty cool just downloaded [this](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26608/my-game-of-life).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One rules of thumb to write idiomatic C++ is:

> Use references where you can and pointers where you have to.

It's especially true for argument passing to a variable.
In your case, you have the choice, so use references, for all the reasons cited by Ilya and also just because you won't have any * to put everywhere in your function. Your code might be clearer that way.

Answer (score 8):

Second one is better. Do not use pointers if it is possible to avoid them.
For example, in the beggining of the function update(Board *board) you have to check that board!=0 (to be sure, that your program will not crash). But in the function update(Board & board) you are sure, that board exists. So second function is better.